# A variant of the graph flow problem

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

I have the following problem: A complete graph with an unknown capacity-function for edge-flow is assumed. The vertices are assumed to not influence flow. I know the source vertex, the amount of flow put into the network, and can observe a binary $0-1$ variable for each edge if there is any flow over it at time $t$ or not. The problem is: Is there a way to determine if the underlying capacity-function is fixed over time $t$? And is there a way to estimate the capacity-function if it is?

Comment: You mention a time $t$; what is supposed to change over time?

Comment: While attempting to clarify my question to answer your comment I stumbled upon the concept of a flow graph and I think this contains the notions I need to examine my problem. Sorry for asking such a poor question.